# how to assign a sequentially increasing number to a relation

Tags: apache-pig

I am wondering if there is a way to create a new field in a relation and then assign some sequentially increasing number to it? Here is one example:

```
ordered_products = ORDER products BY price ASC;
ordered_products_with_sequential_id = FOREACH ordered_products GENERATE price, some_sequential_id;
```

How can I create some_sequential_id? I am not sure whether that's doable in Pig though.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have to write your own UDF to get that running. One way to do it would be by incrementing a static variable (`AtomicInteger`) in your UDF in the `exec` implementation.

```
public class IncrEval extends EvalFunc<Long> {

    final static AtomicLong res = new AtomicLong(0);

    @Override
    public Long exec (Tuple tip) throws IOException {
        if (tip == null || tip.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        res.incrementAndGet();
        return res.longValue();
    }
}
```

Pig script entry:
`b = FOREACH a GENERATE <something>, com.eval.IncrEval() AS ID:long;`

Comment: This is interesting. But would that assign a sequential number to entire relation? I feel like the number would be sequential only within a mapper?

Comment: Yup, thats the disadvantage. You have to set parallelism to 1.